# How to move a div container if container is empty

Tags: css, css-position

My problem is that I don't know how to move a div container, if another container is empty. My structure looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="child1">
        Some content....
    </div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper
    {
    /* nop */
    }

#child1
    {
    transform: translate(0, -3950px);
    }

#child2:empty #child1
    {
    transform: translate(0, -4100px);
    }
```

I know that my #child1 is not inside #child2 but how can I select #child1 if #child2 is empty? Is there a special css trick?

Answer (score -1):

Fun stuff.

You can use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp) and the [:empty](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_empty.asp) pseudo-class, such as:

```
#child2:empty ~ #child1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Make sure you also invert the order of your divs, please see working jsfiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/z0uve835/1/

Comment: That did not work, #child1 is not moving at all, is there another possible solution?

Comment: Apologies, you also have to invert the order of divs, plase see jfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/z0uve835/1/

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the html because it is a wordpress system where the html is loaded dynamically. So would it work if I invert the css instead? Like: #child1 ~ #child2:empty

Comment: There is no css previous sibling selector unfortunately :(

Comment: Oh okay, but thank you very much for your help!